# Error while reading answer from pop server?

Tags: c#, .net, gmail, protocols, pop3

My code connects to pop.gmail.com server and send some commands, but don't receive any data from server. This is my code`

```
  public TcpClient Server;
  public NetworkStream NetStrm;
  public StreamReader RdStrm;
  public string Data;
  public byte[] szData;
  public string CRLF = "\r\n";
  public string Status;

  // initialization
  NetStrm = Server.GetStream();
  RdStrm = new StreamReader(Server.GetStream());
  Status += RdStrm.ReadLine();

  // Login Process
  Data = "USER aaaaaaaa@gmail.com" + CRLF;
  szData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data.ToCharArray());
  NetStrm.Write(szData, 0, szData.Length);
  Status += RdStrm.ReadLine();
  Console.WriteLine(Status);
```

when i debug, there is a message "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine."

Which is problem?

Comment: Sorry I don't know, why not use a library though? http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/

Comment: You call GetStream() twice. Try to put the variable NetStrm in the constructor of the StreamReader()